# How we can get data into api resource when we have morphMany relation

Tags: laravel

I dont want  a json response. I want to use api Resource for this output. Can anyone help me regarding this. Help will be highly appriciated.
This is News Model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;

use Brexis\LaravelWorkflow\Traits\WorkflowTrait;
//use Hyn\Tenancy\Abstracts\TenantModel as TenancyModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    class News extends Model {
        use WorkflowTrait;
    
        protected $table = 'news_info';
        protected $fillable = [
            'title', 'header', 'description', 'status', 'created_by', 'media_url', 'media_thumbnail',
        ];
    
        public function reviews() {
            return $this->morphMany(NewsReview::class, 'reviewable');
        }
    
    
    
        public function reviewsCountByCategory() {
            return $this->morphMany(NewsReview::class, 'reviewable')
                ->select(
                    'reviewable_id',
                    DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN review_reaction=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as review_bad"),
                    DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN review_reaction=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as review_average"),
                    DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN review_reaction=3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as review_good")
                )
                ->groupBy('reviewable_id');
        }
    
    }
```

This is Review model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;

use App\User;
//use Hyn\Tenancy\Abstracts\TenantModel as TenancyModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class NewsReview extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'review_text',
        'review_reaction',
        'is_visible',
        'reviewed_by',
        'reviewable_id',
        'reviewable_type'
    ];

    public function reviewable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
     public function news(){
         return $this->belongsTo(News::class);
     }
    public function reviewer() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'reviewed_by');
    }
}
```

This is my function inside Controller

```
public function searchNews(Request $request,$title) {
        try {
            $result=News::with('reviewsCountByCategory')->where('status', 'pre_validation')
                ->where('title', 'LIKE',"%$title%")
                ->orderBy('title', 'asc')->paginate(3);
                        return response()->json(['status' => TRUE, 'data' => $result], 200);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['status' => FALSE, 'msg' => 'Internal Server Error','error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
```

This is current response I am getting now

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "title": "AndraPradesh CM Tested Positive",
                "header": "Todays Headline",
                "description": "Corona Virus spreds Globaly",
                "status": "pre_validation",
                "created_by": 2,
                "media_type": null,
                "media_url": "www.abc.com",
                "media_thumbnail": null,
                "is_send_with_newsletter": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-07-24 11:28:34",
                "updated_at": "2020-07-24 11:28:34",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "reviews_count_by_category": []
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Anurag singh",
                "header": "Todayfdfdf",
                "description": "Hoell",
                "status": "pre_validation",
                "created_by": 1,
                "media_type": null,
                "media_url": "www.abc.com",
                "media_thumbnail": null,
                "is_send_with_newsletter": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-07-22 11:13:50",
                "updated_at": "2020-07-22 11:13:50",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "reviews_count_by_category": [
                    {
                        "reviewable_id": 2,
                        "review_bad": 0,
                        "review_average": 1,
                        "review_good": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "title": "Chandigarh is famous for its natural Beauty",
                "header": "Todays Headline",
                "description": "Corona Virus spreds Globaly",
                "status": "pre_validation",
                "created_by": 2,
                "media_type": null,
                "media_url": "www.abc.com",
                "media_thumbnail": null,
                "is_send_with_newsletter": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-07-24 11:29:18",
                "updated_at": "2020-07-24 11:29:18",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "reviews_count_by_category": []
            }
        ],
```

This is my Review resource

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Transformers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ReviewResource extends Resource {
    /**
     * @param Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'review_id'       => $this->id,
            'review_text'     => $this->review_text,
            'review_reaction' => new NewsResource($this->reviewsCountByCategory),
            'is_visible'      => $this->is_visible,
            'reviewed_by'     => new UserResource($this->reviewer),
            'news'            => new NewsResource($this->reviews),
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my NewsResource

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Transformers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class NewsResource extends Resource {
    /**
     * @param Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'news_id'                 => $this->id,
            'title'                   => $this->title,
            'header'                  => $this->header,
            'description'             => $this->description,
            'status'                  => $this->status,
            'media_url'               => $this->media_url,
            'media_thumbnail'         => $this->media_thumbnail,
        ];
    }
}
```

But I dont want  a json response. I want to use api Resource for this output. Can anyone help me regarding this. Help will be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function in the controller, instead of this

```
return response()->json(['status' => TRUE, 'data' => $result], 200);
```

NewsResource.php

```
    public function toArray($request) {
        $reviews = [];
        foreach($this->reviews as $review){
            array_push($reviews, [
                'review_id'       => $review->id,
                'review_text'     => $review->review_text,
                'is_visible'      => $review->is_visible,
            ]);
        }
        return [
            'news_id'                 => $this->id,
            'title'                   => $this->title,
            'header'                  => $this->header,
            'description'             => $this->description,
            'status'                  => $this->status,
            'media_url'               => $this->media_url,
            'media_thumbnail'         => $this->media_thumbnail,
            'reviews' => $reviews,
        ];
    }
```

Use the NewsResource

```
return NewsResource::collection($result);
```

Comment: This will give only the news details. I want all news with their reviews.

Comment: Yeah, you can edit the NewsResource to include that. Share your NewsResource and I'll help you to do it.

Comment: I have added it in the question. Please review it

Comment: I've updated the answer, and added the reviews along with it. You can add other relation data in a similar manner.

Comment: public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'news'=>    new NewsResource($this->reviewable),
            'review_id'       => $this->id,
            'review_reaction' => $this->reviewsCountByCategory,

        ];
    }
By using this I am getting everything working. I just want know how I can access the news now. bucause it is giving null.

Comment: I didn't get you, the NewsResource that I added contains the news data as well as the reviews, what's the problem with it?

Comment: I am saying that This is my code of Review Resource. I getting everything ok. Only   I am not able to get news details. Can you tel me how I can get news details using details.

public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'news'=>    new NewsResource(),
            'review_id'       => $this->id,
            'review_reaction' => $this->reviewsCountByCategory,

        ];
    }

Comment: If you want news in your reviewResource, use the news relation that you've created in the Review model

Comment: You'll have to pass Reviews Model instance into the ReviewResource and as I can see in the post your ReviewResource is calling relations that are not defined in your Review Model. You're using the relations that are of the News Model.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I found the solution in your code.

Comment: Okay, that's great :)